# System.Data.DataRowView error

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql, project

So, I.ve actually googled a lot about that error, but some of the code that had a solution I couldn't understand, mainly because I'm new at c#, so I'll just put the problem as it is.

My professors called it "complex winform". That's basically data from 2 different tables that are linked with an inner join. So far so good.

I work with postgresql btw.

I have 2 main tables. Student (with idstudent, registrationid, yearofstudy) and Persons( with idperson, Name, Telephone, Email, etc). (idstudent = idperson)

There are around 20 PERSONS in my database and 7 STUDENTS. Students are also persons (duuh), ergo idstudent=idperson.

So, I have a combobox where i put a disctinct  yearofstudy of all my students and it looks like this.

```
private void frmComplex1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OdbcConnection conexiune;
    conexiune = new OdbcConnection();
    conexiune.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=postgres;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;fakeoidindex=0;showoidcolumn=0;rowversioning=0;showsystemtables=0;fetch=100;unknownsizes=0;maxvarcharsize=255;maxlongvarcharsize=8190;debug=0;commlog=0;usedeclarefetch=0;textaslongvarchar=1;unknownsaslongvarchar=0;boolsaschar=1;parse=0;extrasystableprefixes=dd_;lfconversion=1;updatablecursors=1;trueisminus1=0;bi=0;byteaaslongvarbinary=0;useserversideprepare=1;lowercaseidentifier=0;gssauthusegss=0;xaopt=1;pwd=irimia96";
    conexiune.Open();

    OdbcCommand comanda;
    comanda = new OdbcCommand();
    comanda.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT anstudiu from studenti ORDER BY anstudiu asc ";
    comanda.Connection = conexiune;

    OdbcDataReader cititor;
   cititor = comanda.ExecuteReader();

    DataSet dsDate;
    dsDate = new DataSet();
    DataTable tblStudenti;
    tblStudenti = new DataTable("studenti");
    tblStudenti.Load(cititor);
    dsDate.Tables.Add(tblStudenti);

    this.cboComplex1.DataSource = dsDate.Tables["studenti"];
    this.cboComplex1.DisplayMember = "anstudiu";
    this.cboComplex1.ValueMember = "anstudiu";








    conexiune.Close();
}
```

So what im trying to do is, whenever I select a year (1/2/3) from that combobox, to get in return, in  my first DataGrindView Information about students that are year 1/2/3 from BOTH STUDENT table and PERSON TABLE. For example: the students from yearofstudy 2  with. IdPerson, Name, Telephone, Email, RegistrationId, Student Id. (I know Student Id and Person Id will get the same value, but I dont care, first let it work)

So i type the script, and get this the datarawview error

```
private void cboComplex1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OdbcConnection conexiune;
    OdbcCommand comanda;
    DataSet dsDate;
    OdbcDataReader cititor;
    DataTable tblPersoane;


    conexiune = new OdbcConnection();
    conexiune.ConnectionString = " Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI};database=postgres;server=localhost;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;fakeoidindex=0;showoidcolumn=0;rowversioning=0;showsystemtables=0;fetch=100;unknownsizes=0;maxvarcharsize=255;maxlongvarcharsize=8190;debug=0;commlog=0;usedeclarefetch=0;textaslongvarchar=1;unknownsaslongvarchar=0;boolsaschar=1;parse=0;extrasystableprefixes=dd_;lfconversion=1;updatablecursors=1;trueisminus1=0;bi=0;byteaaslongvarbinary=0;useserversideprepare=1;lowercaseidentifier=0;gssauthusegss=0;xaopt=1;pwd=irimia96";
    conexiune.Open();

    comanda = new OdbcCommand();
    comanda.CommandText = "SELECT * from persoane INNER JOIN studenti on persoane.idpersoana = studenti.idstudent WHERE anstudiu =?";
    comanda.Connection = conexiune;


    comanda.Parameters.Clear();
    comanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("anstudiu", cboComplex1.SelectedValue.ToString());

    cititor = comanda.ExecuteReader();
    tblPersoane = new DataTable("persoane");
    tblPersoane.Load(cititor);
    dsDate = new DataSet();
    dsDate.Tables.Add(tblPersoane);

    dGComplex.DataSource = dsDate;
    dGComplex.DataMember = "persoane";
    dGComplex.Refresh();


}
```

Srry for the long post, i'll give you a potato at the end.

Comment: No it is not better with pictures. It is difficult to read, it is impossible to copy/paste to test. Post your code. By the way. What is the error?

Comment: I see it now. The problem is in the code used to fill the combobox. You have set the DataSource with a DataTable but forget to set the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and see what `cboComplex1.SelectedValue.ToString()` returns?  Most likely it's returning an object of type `System.Data.DataRowView`, not the value your're looking for. Also, note that if the column type is an Integer, you'll have to parse the string to an int before passing it in.

Comment: @Steve To be honest, I have a very nice example from my profs. I adapted line with line to my form. I didnt skiped one line. He had an displaymember and ValueMember in the combo box in the Form_Load. As you can see in the script above. But for DataGrindView (dGComplex in my example) he didnt had any.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange the column in postgres is numeric, indeed, but.. I swear I dont know how to convert it from visual..

Comment: @Steve I'm embarrassed now.. Jesus.. thank you so much.. I spent 5 hours today with this.. and in 30 minutes I got it here.

Comment: Yes I know the feeling... see you again on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just invert the order of the settings for DisplayMember/ValueMember in relation to the setting of the DataSource property

```
this.cboComplex1.DisplayMember = "anstudiu";
this.cboComplex1.ValueMember = "anstudiu";
// Move this line after setting the Disply/ValueMember property
this.cboComplex1.DataSource = dsDate.Tables["studenti"];
```

This should ensure the proper binding of the strings used for Display/ValueMember against the field names of the datatable.
I should add that this mode doesn't catch an error if you mistype one of your field names (for example "anstdiu" will be accepted).
On the contrary, if you set the DataSource before the Display/ValueMember, trying to write an invalid name will get you a runtime exception.